# Auto Mapper is keeping a reference while mapping

Tags: c#, oop, automapper

I am trying to clone an object in a way that i get a fresh copy of existing instance.

I am using AutoMapper  like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap(typeof(VariableSet), typeof(VariableSet));
var destinationObject = Mapper.Map<VariableSet>(command.VariableSets[0]);
command.VariableSets.Add(destinationObject);
```

I have an array:

```
command.VariableSets
```

I am trying to add another instance of the object that is at 0th index of this array. but when i use auto mapper it creates another instance by reference. So if i change any sub property in 0th index object, it also gets updated in 1st index object.

i tried cloning the object using serialization deserialization method but than i have to make my objects `[Serializable]` which has its own issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new object manually and then map object-to-object:

```
var destinationObject = 
    Mapper.Map<VariableSet, VariableSet>(command.VariableSets[0], new VariableSet());
```

The same logic may be applied for each reference type property of `VariableSet` if you need to create new objects for it too.

Howewer, there are several ways to create an object's copy. For example you may  implement `ICloneable` interface and then use `Clone` method. It gaves you full control of deep copying and don't require AutoMapper tool. You can find ton of information here:

[Deep cloning objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects)